# ionic 2 npm WARN @angular/router@4.2.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.2.5 but none was installed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have this warning message.
Whenever I am trying to install any plugin like

```
npm install slick-carousel --save
```

It just through this warning-
[image]

What I have tried so for-
https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/using-npm/   
remove and used latest one-
http://devfanaticblog.com/how-to-update-ionic-2-cli-and-libraries/
and follow the steps but does not make any sense for me.
also try manually to update that but ....!
here is the local setup-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

here is package.json--

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-touchswipe": "^1.6.15",
    "ng2-breadcrumb": "^0.5.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-tslint": "^1.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "^0.0.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    },
    "android",
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ],
  "name": "app name",
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Can any one help me to do so !!!

Comment: Can you put your packages.config file in?

Comment: Just update with package.json @Migol

Answer (score 1):

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3"
```

This part is your problem - you depend on Angular 2.0 RC3 (VERY old one) while some other package rquires current version of 4.2.5.

Change those lines to:

```
"@angular/common": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
"@angular/core": "4.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
"@angular/http": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
"@angular/router": "4.2.5",
```

Comment: I did the above and have after npm update - 
npm WARN @angular/core@4.2.5 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@4.2.5 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@4.2.5 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@4.2.5 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.0.0-rc.3 but none wa

Comment: Looks like you have a REALLY old template. ionic-angular is now at version 3.5. I would say that you start from scratch.

Do `npm install -g ionic` and then you will have ionic command. Using it you should be able to bootstrap a working project.

Comment: That is the last option, we don't have any other alternative for the same?